# Run a loop based on vector elements

Tags: r, loops, merge

I have to run a loop based on certain vector values. Some example code and data is shown below:

```
list_store <- list()
vec <- c(3,2,3)
data_list <- lapply(list(head(mtcars,10), head(mtcars,15), head(mtcars,20), head(mtcars, 9),
                         head(mtcars,14), head(mtcars,18), head(mtcars,20), head(mtcars,10)),
                    function(x) rownames_to_column(x))
data_list1 <- lapply(list(head(mtcars,7), head(mtcars,8), head(mtcars,10)), function(x) rownames_to_column(x))
result <- lapply(data_list, function(i){
  list_store[[length(list_store) + 1]] <- merge(i, data_list1[[1]], all.y = TRUE)
})
```

The above code is that I want to merge first three files of `data_list` with first file of `data_list1`, the next two files of `data_list` with second file of `data_list1` and finally the other three files of `data_list` with the third file of `data_list1`. In my code I merge all the files of `data_list` with the first file of `data_list1`, but I want to change `data_list1` as per `vec`

I can have a loop keeping track of `i`, `j` and so on to do all the process, but I want to know if there is any efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `replicate` the 'vec' by the sequence of 'vec', use that to `split` the 'data_list' into 3 `list` elements each having a `list`.  Then, use `Map` to pass the corresponding `list` elements from the `split` dataset and 'data_list1', loop through the nested `list` with `lapply` and `merge` with the elements of 'data_list1', use `c` to convert the nested `list` back to the normal `list` structure of 'data_list'.

```
do.call(c, 
    Map(function(x,y) lapply(x, function(dat) 
                            merge(dat, y, all.y = TRUE)), 
         split(data_list, rep(seq_along(vec), vec)),
          data_list1))
```

Comment: Thanks ... a bit of explanation  will be helpful.

Comment: @AaghazHussain  Thanks, added the explanation

Comment: I can say `R` legendary @akrun :)

Comment: @AaghazHussain  Thank you for the big words, I am still a humble learner..

Comment: Till now the above code was very fine but today I got `Warning: Error in do.call: 'what' must be a function or character string`

Comment: @AaghazHussain  Did you created an object with `c` i.e. `c <- 42` or so.  In that case use `c` with backquotes

Comment: No, I didn't do any like that but using "c" solved the problem. I am surprised!!

Comment: @AaghazHussain  May be it could be after effect of some objects.  Try it on a clean session

Comment: Exactly. So it means "c" is an every time solution if an object with c is created inadvertently.